# Is there a way to calculate how different two 2d arrays are from one another?

Tags: pytorch, loss-function, sudoku, conv-neural-network

I am attempting to make a sudoku solver using a CNN. I am wondering if there is a way I can  calculate the loss between  the output puzzle and the without using a fully connected layer? If yes how?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.
Can you share some code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-sudoku-with-convolution-neural-network-keras-655ba4be3b11) example, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` have been proposed as a loss function for learning to solve sudoku in a supervised manner.

It has been also stated that in "SCC loss, you don't need to provide a one-hot encoded target vector." So you will provide the output and the target as-is.